# Retain ckeditor formatting in exported pdf using itext

Tags: formatting, ckeditor, itext

I am exporting a report in pdf using itext.In report a paragraph text is fetched from ckeditor.I want to retain the text formatting of ckeditor textarea in pdf also.For eg if ckeditor text contains bullets, in pdf bullets should be shown with the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this demo: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

In this case, we use TinyMCE as editor, but you can easily replace it with CKEditor (we flipped a coin and decided to go for TinyMCE, but we could as well have gone for CKEditor). These editors produce XHTML. This XHTML can be fed to iText's XML Worker.

You can find XML Worker examples [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker). The simplest example looks like this:

```
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
// step 3
document.open();
// step 4
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
        new FileInputStream(HTML));
// step 5
document.close();
```

It gets more complex if images are involved, special fonts, CSS, etc... That's what the other examples are about.

Comment: Bullets are not getting displayed in pdf instead a different character is being displayed in place of bullet.

Comment: That's configurable, isn't it?

Comment: i didn't get.How to configure ?

Comment: With CSS: `list-style-type:disk`.